# Two xml in one xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi can i do this in a xslt , and if yes then how..?
I have one xml file which contains one element called 'reasonCode' , this reason code is mapped to different 'reasonText' in another xml.What i hae to do is check the 'reasonCode' from first xml and select the corresponding 'reasonText' from second xml.Can i do this using XSLT...if yes then please give me brief idea how..??

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [`document()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#document) function to access another XML document. For example:

```
<xsl:template match="reasonCode">
  <xsl:variable name="code" select="."/>
  <xsl:value-of select="document('another.xml')//reasonText[@code = $code]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: You even can replace `'another.xml'` with a value of the source document like e.g. an attribute: `document(@href)`.

Answer (score 2):

Merge the two files under a new parent tag and send the whole thing through the XSLT.

Comment: but both of my xml have different structure , wont it create a problem.
I will use document(abc.xml) command in xslt to merge...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Abraham's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26222/abraham-pinzur) answer. I have written combineNavigableDocuments() methods in PHP, Java and C# to deal with this type of problem. You can also use the [XSLT document function](http://www.w3schools.com/Xsl/func_document.asp) but this can lead to unexpected permissions problems in security-aware platforms like .NET.