# Merging template XML with Old Data XMLs

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have to a template XML and a old data XML which may not be having the same structure as the template.

I need to create a new data XML based on the template XML and populate it with values from the old data XML if they are present.

e.g. 
Template XML -

```
<tag1></tag1>
<tag3></tag3>
```

Old Data XML -

```
<tag1>value1</tag1>
<tag2>value2</tag2>
```

New Data XML -

```
<tag1>value1</tag1>
<tag3></tag3>
```

I need to achieve this using Java. 
Can this be done using Java XSL Transformers? Or do I need some External APIs?

Answer (score 0):

There is an interesting thread here that talks about the same thing.

[XSLT: A simple way to merge xml files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510688/xslt-a-simple-way-to-merge-xml-files)

Hope this will help you.