# change data from an XML file getting data from another

Tags: xml

I have 2 xml files:

file1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="../helpproject.xsl" ?>
<topic template="Default" lasteditedby="fjuras" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../helpproject.xsd">
 <body>
  <para><text>Enter the </text><lang>button1</lang><text>by tapping the list icon</text></para>
 </body>
</topic>
```

file2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<language id="lang.main" name="English (British)" iso="GBR" langIso="ENG" charset="roman" charsetSpecial="special" usingCJK="no" R2L="no">
 <lang id="button1" text="Menu"/>
</language>
```

My problem is that I want to replace the button1 in file1 with Menu from the file2. I have to do this, because the names from the file2 are changing a lot, but ids stays the same. I cannot modify the file helpproject.xsl. This file is the final stylesheet. I want to be made this modification before displayng the content. I would like to do this or by writing something directly in the file1 or making some new external xsl file which will do this.
If there is any posibility to do this please respond me, cause I'm now out of any idea how can this be made.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could find your hapiness [with this related subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510688/xslt-a-simple-way-to-merge-xml-files) which handle to merge the two files.

Once it did you can finish with some xsl transformation.

hope this could help

Kind of regards