# How to merge two XML files have the same parameters?

Tags: java, xml, dom, jaxb, transformer-model

I want to merge two XML files(source file & temp file) and put the resulted file in the source file and both source and temp files have the same elements but with different values like :

**Source.xml:**

```
<Main>
   <source>
        <param>
            <entry>
                <key> bla1 </key>
                <value> bla1 </value>
            </entry> 
        </param>
        <Name> name1 </Name>
   </Source> 
</Main>
```

**And temp.xml:**

```
<Main>
   <source>
        <param>
           <entry>
               <key> bla2 </key>
               <value> bla2 </value>
           </entry>
           <entry>
               <key> bla3 </key>
               <value> bla3 </value>
           </entry>  
        </param>
        <Name> name2 </Name>
   </Source> 
</Main>
```

**And the desired output i want it like :**

```
<Main>
  <source>
        <param>
            <entry>
                <key> bla1 </key>
                <value> bla1 </value>
            </entry> 
        </param>
        <Name> name1 </Name>
   </Source> 
   <source>
        <param>

           <entry>
               <key> bla2 </key>
               <value> bla2 </value>
           </entry>
           <entry>
               <key> bla3 </key>
               <value> bla3 </value>
           </entry>  
        </param>
        <Name> name2 </Name>
   </Source> 
</Main>
```

I'm using this code but it does't affect the **source.xml** at all :

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class MergeXml {

    private static final String fileName = "Source.xml";
    private static final String tempName = "temp.xml";
    private static final String mainTag = "XmlSource";
    private static final String YES = "yes";


    public void mergeXML() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException,
            IOException, TransformerException {

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = null;
        Document doc = null;
        Document doc2 = null;

        db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = db.parse(new File(fileName));
        doc2 = db.parse(new File(tempName));
        Element tag = doc.createElement(mainTag);

        NodeList nodeList = doc2.getElementsByTagName("*");

        for(int i =0 ; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++){

            Node node = nodeList.item(i);
            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                String nodeName = node.getNodeName();
                Element tagChild = doc.createElement((nodeName));

                tag.appendChild(tagChild);
            }
        }

        TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, YES);

        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
        transformer.transform(source, result);

        BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
        String xmlOutput = result.getWriter().toString();
        output.write(xmlOutput);
        output.close();

    }
}
```

**My XML Original File if needed:**

```
   <XmlSource>
         <hostName>api.worldweatheronline.com</hostName>
         <parameters>
             <entry>
                 <key>num_of_days</key>
                 <value>1</value>
             </entry>
             <entry>
                 <key>q</key>
                 <value>Cairo</value>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                 <key>format</key>
                 <value>xml</value>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                 <key>key</key>
                 <value>wd63kxr294rcgvbynhaf2z4r</value>
            </entry>
       </parameters>
       <URL>
        http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=Cairo&format=xml&num_of_days=1&key=wd63kxr294rcgvbynhaf2z4r
      </URL>
      <URLPath>/free/v1/weather.ashx</URLPath>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code snippet which you can use to merge two xml.

```
public static void generateDocument(Document root, Document insertDoc, String toPath, String fromPath) {

    if (null != root) {



        try {
              Node element = getNode(insertDoc, fromPath);
              Node dest = root.importNode(element, true);
            Node node = getNode(root, toPath);
            node.insertBefore(dest, null);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
           System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
public Node getNode(Document doc, String strXpathExpression)
            throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException,
            XPathExpressionException {

        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

        // XPath Query for showing all nodes value
        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(strXpathExpression);

        Node node = (Node) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);

        return node;
    }
```

Hence your appraoch would be 
1. Create a document obj(obj1) of Soruce.xml
2. Create a document obj(obj2) of test.xml and remove Main tag.

```
            DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc1 = builder.parse(new File("s1.xml"));
            Document doc2 = builder.parse(new File("s2.xml"));
            generateDocument(doc1,doc2,"/Main", "Main/source");
```

1. Call the method mentioned generateDocument(obj1, obj2, "/Main")

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible to merge xml files. You can refer below links to merge your file. Do necessary changes in code of below links to achieve structure of your XML. 
[Merge Two XML Files in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648471/merge-two-xml-files-in-java)

[Merging xml file using java NodeList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568995/merging-xml-file-using-java-nodelist)

[Merging xml file using java NodeList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568995/merging-xml-file-using-java-nodelist)

Comment: I shared my original XML file

Answer (score 0):

> XML file merge without tag names:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class test {

public static void mergeXML(){


    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = null;
    Document doc = null;
    Document doc2 = null;

    try {
            db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = db.parse(new File("f1.xml"));
            doc2 = db.parse(new File("f2.xml"));
            NodeList ndListFirstFile = doc.getElementsByTagName("staffs");

            Node pndListFirstFile2 = doc2.getElementsByTagName("company").item(0);
            NodeList pchildren = pndListFirstFile2.getChildNodes();
            for(int i=0;i<pchildren.getLength();i++) {
                if(pchildren.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element pelem = (Element)pchildren.item(i);
                    // If your document is namespace aware use localName
                    String plocalName = pelem.getLocalName();
                    // Tag name returns the localName and the namespace prefix
                    String ptagName= pelem.getTagName();
                    // do stuff with the children
                    System.out.print(ptagName);
                   Node ndListFirstFile2 = doc2.getElementsByTagName(ptagName).item(0);
                    NodeList children = ndListFirstFile2.getChildNodes();
                     for(int ii=0;ii<children.getLength();ii++) {
                        if(children.item(ii).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                            Element elem = (Element)children.item(ii);
                            // If your document is namespace aware use localName
                            String localName = elem.getLocalName();
                            // Tag name returns the localName and the namespace prefix
                            String tagName= elem.getTagName();
                            // do stuff with the children
                            System.out.print(tagName);
                            Node nodeArea = doc.importNode(doc2.getElementsByTagName(tagName).item(0), true);
                            ndListFirstFile.item(0).appendChild(nodeArea);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }



          TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
          Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();
          transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");  

          DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
          StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
          transformer.transform(source, result); 

          Writer output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("f3.xml"));
          String xmlOutput = result.getWriter().toString();  
          output.write(xmlOutput);
          output.close();

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, TransformerException{
    mergeXML();
}
```

}