# Merge XML in java having few multiple node's tag name same as child?

Tags: java, xml, merge, tagname

I have a problem to merge two XML string or File.

XML1.

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Specification>
 <item>
  <id>PS1</id>
  <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
  <Product>
   <item>
    <id>P1</id>
    <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
   </item>
   <item>
    <id>P2</id>
    <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
   </item>
  </Product>
  <CompositePrice>
   <item>
    <id>PR1</id>
    <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
    <Price>1.0</Price>
   </item>
   <item>
    <id>PR2</id>
    <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
    <Price>2.0</Price>
   </item>
  </Price>
 </item>
 <item>
  <id>PS2</id>
  <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
  <Product>
   <item>
    <id>P3</id>
    <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
   </item>
   <item>
    <id>P4</id>
    <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
   </item>
  </Product>
  <CompositePrice>
   <item>
    <id>PR3</id>
    <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
    <Price>1.0</Price>
   </item>
   <item>
    <id>PR4</id>
    <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
    <Price>2.0</Price>
   </item>
  </Price>
 </item>
</Specification>
```

XML2.

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Specification>
 <item>
  <id>PS3</id>
  <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
  <Product>
   <item>
    <id>P5</id>
    <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
   </item>
   <item>
    <id>P6</id>
    <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
   </item>
  </Product>
  <CompositePrice>
   <item>
    <id>PR5</id>
    <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
    <Price>1.0</Price>
   </item>
   <item>
    <id>PR6</id>
    <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
    <Price>2.0</Price>
   </item>
  </Price>
 </item>
 <item>
  <id>PS1</id>
  <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
  <Product>
   <item>
    <id>P7</id>
    <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
   </item>
   <item>
    <id>P8</id>
    <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
   </item>
  </Product>
  <CompositePrice>
   <item>
    <id>PR3</id>
    <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
    <Price>1.0</Price>
   </item>
   <item>
    <id>PR4</id>
    <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
    <Price>2.0</Price>
   </item>
  </Price>
 </item>
</Specification>
```

Expected Output:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Specification>
 <item>
  <id>PS1</id>
  <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
  <Product>
   <item>
    <id>P1</id>
    <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
   </item>
   <item>
    <id>P2</id>
    <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
   </item>
  </Product>
  <CompositePrice>
   <item>
    <id>PR1</id>
    <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
    <Price>1.0</Price>
   </item>
   <item>
    <id>PR2</id>
    <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
    <Price>2.0</Price>
   </item>
  </Price>
 </item>
 <item>
  <id>PS2</id>
  <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
  <Product>
   <item>
    <id>P3</id>
    <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
   </item>
   <item>
    <id>P4</id>
    <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
   </item>
  </Product>
  <CompositePrice>
   <item>
    <id>PR3</id>
    <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
    <Price>1.0</Price>
   </item>
   <item>
    <id>PR4</id>
    <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
    <Price>2.0</Price>
   </item>
  </Price>
 </item>
 <item>
  <id>PS3</id>
  <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
  <Product>
   <item>
    <id>P5</id>
    <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
   </item>
   <item>
    <id>P6</id>
    <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
   </item>
  </Product>
  <CompositePrice>
   <item>
    <id>PR5</id>
    <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
    <Price>1.0</Price>
   </item>
   <item>
    <id>PR6</id>
    <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
    <Price>2.0</Price>
   </item>
  </Price>
 </item>
 <item>
  <id>PS1</id>
  <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
  <Product>
   <item>
    <id>P7</id>
    <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
   </item>
   <item>
    <id>P8</id>
    <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
   </item>
  </Product>
  <CompositePrice>
   <item>
    <id>PR3</id>
    <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
    <Price>1.0</Price>
   </item>
   <item>
    <id>PR4</id>
    <startDate> 21 Oct 2016</startDate>
    <Price>2.0</Price>
   </item>
  </Price>
 </item>
</Specification>
```

I tried to run a java code, but failing to merge when second code have multiple item under Specification.
Running okay when second have only single item even when first have multiple Items under specification.

Comment: check this links : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648471/merge-two-xml-files-in-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568995/merging-xml-file-using-java-nodelist

Comment: Just for the information, your XML 1 and XML 2 are not valid XMLs. The element type "CompositePrice" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</CompositePrice>".

Comment: Thanks John for highlighting the same.