# Easiest way to inject SVG-object into an existing SVG-file

Tags: xml, svg

What I would like to do is to take an existing SVG-File and introduce an object that is defined on another SVG-file (on previously defined coordinates and at a defined zoom-setting).
The new object should be simply overlaid.

Is there an easy way to do this on the command line without having to analyze the existing SVG-file? (for example insert the code from the new object before the last XML-tag or after the first, or to use Inkscape as a command-line tool, etc.)

Comment: How about using XSLT. You could use a utility like saxon from the command line with a xslt style sheet like the one in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510688/xslt-a-simple-way-to-merge-xml-files

Answer (score 0):

You could put a `<use>` element in the file that points to the other file.

Not all UAs support external `<use>` links though. Firefox does and Opera 12 did.