# Merging multiple XML files using Java

Tags: java, xml

I have a code to merge two xml files but the results i expected was different.

**XML 1:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<testsuite errors="0" failures="0" name="unit.qa.fm" tests="14" time="3182.09">
<properties/>
<testcase classname="com.ca.clarity.unit.financial.transaction.CBKRuleForAllFTP42249QAUTest" name="invoiceAdjustments" testCaseID="42249" time="175.548"/>
<testcase classname="com.ca.clarity.unit.financial.transaction.CreateWIPAdjustmentChangingRateReflectInInvoice42207QAUTest" name="invoiceAdjustments42207" testCaseID="42207" time="171.971"/>
</testsuite>
```

**XML 2:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<testsuite errors="0" failures="0" name="unit.qa.fm" tests="10" time="1647.807">
<properties/>
<testcase classname="com.ca.clarity.unit.financial.setup.CheckDepartmentAndDepartmentOBSAreInSync58786QAUTest" name="CheckDeptAndDeptOBSAreInSync" testCaseID="58786" time="27.132"/>
<testcase classname="com.ca.clarity.unit.financial.setup.DepartmentXogQAUTest" name="validateDepartmentXogIn" testCaseID="52082" time="11.097"/>
</testsuite>
```

**Expected result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><testsuite errors="0" failures="0" name="unit.qa.fm" tests="14" time="3182.09">
  <properties/>
  <testcase classname="com.ca.clarity.unit.financial.transaction.CBKRuleForAllFTP42249QAUTest" name="invoiceAdjustments" testCaseID="42249" time="175.548"/>
  <testcase classname="com.ca.clarity.unit.financial.transaction.CreateWIPAdjustmentChangingRateReflectInInvoice42207QAUTest" name="invoiceAdjustments42207" testCaseID="42207" time="171.971"/>
  <testcase classname="com.ca.clarity.unit.financial.setup.CheckDepartmentAndDepartmentOBSAreInSync58786QAUTest" name="CheckDeptAndDeptOBSAreInSync" testCaseID="58786" time="27.132"/>
  <testcase classname="com.ca.clarity.unit.financial.setup.DepartmentXogQAUTest" name="validateDepartmentXogIn" testCaseID="52082" time="11.097"/>
</testsuite>
```

**Actual I am getting**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><testsuite errors="0" failures="0" name="unit.qa.fm" tests="14" time="3182.09">
  <properties/>
  <testcase classname="com.ca.clarity.unit.financial.transaction.CBKRuleForAllFTP42249QAUTest" name="invoiceAdjustments" testCaseID="42249" time="175.548"/>
  <testcase classname="com.ca.clarity.unit.financial.transaction.CreateWIPAdjustmentChangingRateReflectInInvoice42207QAUTest" name="invoiceAdjustments42207" testCaseID="42207" time="171.971"/>
  <testcase classname="com.ca.clarity.unit.financial.setup.CheckDepartmentAndDepartmentOBSAreInSync58786QAUTest" name="CheckDeptAndDeptOBSAreInSync" testCaseID="58786" time="27.132"/>
  <testcase classname="com.ca.clarity.unit.financial.setup.DepartmentXogQAUTest" name="validateDepartmentXogIn" testCaseID="52082" time="11.097"/>
</testsuite><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><testsuite errors="0" failures="0" name="unit.qa.fm" tests="10" time="1647.807">
  <properties/>
  <testcase classname="com.ca.clarity.unit.financial.setup.CheckDepartmentAndDepartmentOBSAreInSync58786QAUTest" name="CheckDeptAndDeptOBSAreInSync" testCaseID="58786" time="27.132"/>
  <testcase classname="com.ca.clarity.unit.financial.setup.DepartmentXogQAUTest" name="validateDepartmentXogIn" testCaseID="52082" time="11.097"/>
</testsuite>
```

Can anyone help me to add only testcase node to existing XML file not the whole content.

Thanks,

Comment: you should add some information to the post.

Comment: Here's a clever [XSLT technique for merging XML files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510688/xslt-a-simple-way-to-merge-xml-files).

Comment: Looks like you did the Java version of `cat foo.xml bar.xml`, so you've got an extra DTD in there and two root elements.